# JavaFX MediaPlayer shows nothing?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to load a media file but all i get it a blank white screen, but i can hear the file playing.  The file is in a folder called resources within my project.

Here is the code.

```
public class ScreenSaverController implements IControlledScreen {

    Main app;

    public void setApp(Main application) {
        app = application;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/screenSaver.mp4");

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(url.toString()));

        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

My FXML file, just contains this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="1024.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" fitHeight="1024.0" fitWidth="1280.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

As i said i can hear the file but nothing shows.  I have tried with mp4 and flv versions of the same file and both do the same thing, sound but no video.

If i change my code to this, i can see a video

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv"));
```

I have upgraded my jdk to version 1.8.0_31 and still the same.

Anyone know what i am doing wrong?  Am i supposed to do something when using a local file?

Comment: The [JavaFX media javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) details supported codecs for JavaFX - ensure that your video is encoded using a supported codec.  Also add the error handling mentioned on the javadoc page to troubleshoot any media playback errors.  Ensure that your system meets a [minimum certified configuration for JavaFX media playback](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

Comment: I have now encoded the video using VLC, and now the video opens, but doesnt play.  I have used the example code from the link you sent and i now get an error saying Handle asynchronous error in MediaView: [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@5ae950da] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID

Comment: It would seem that your media file is not correctly encoded to a format that JavaFX can understand.

Comment: Is there a convertor to use to get it right? Would of thought that vlc would be fine be obviously not then

Answer (score 0):

make sure your video is an original one, I had the same problem with a video I recorded from my computer and converted it to a mp4, it plays but I can't see but when I used an original one, it played and showed at the same time.
I also discovered I had extension wmv and avi not supported.

I hope you will fix your problem with this.